# RSpec for should_receive and should_not_receive both passed for Exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I had a really weird rspec case scenario. I tried to test if my function handles exception correctly. And the following is my code:

in User.rb:

```
def welcome_user
      begin
        send_welcome_mail(self)
      rescue Exception => exception
         ErrorMessage.add(exception, user_id: self.id)
      end
    end
end
```

in user_spec.rb

```
it "adds to error message if an exception is thrown" do
  mock_user = User.new
  mock_user.stub(:send_welcome_mail).and_raise(Exception)
  ErrorMessage.should_receive(:add)
  mock_user.welcome_user
end
```

The test passed, but when I change `ErrorMessage.should_receive(:add)` to `ErrorMessage.should_not_receive(:add)`, It also passed, any insights?

Comment: I have come across a test with the same thing happening, but it goes away with rspec 2.11. See if that makes a difference for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since rspec 2.11 exposed one of my tests to exhibit such "abnormality", I decided to raise the issue on github. You may following the discussion at https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/164

**Summary**: any_instance.should_not_receive is undefined, avoid

Comment: I eventually managed to resolve this issue, it turns out the method I stubbed out with exception was also called somewhere before in the logic flow, which was the major issue of the problem.

Answer (score 5):

What you can try to use instead is `.should_receive` in combination with [`.never`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-mocks/RSpec/Mocks/MessageExpectation#never-instance_method):

```
ErrorMessage.should_receive(:add).never
```