# Workaround to `should_receive` and `should_not_receive` in rspec 2.10.x?

Tags: ruby, rspec, specifications

I've a very strange problem when I was writing some tests with `should_receive` and `should_not_receive` for a legacy project.

It was using `rspec-rails 2.10.x`, which can be upgraded to lastest `rspec-rails 2.x`. But since the code is complex, we can't reproduce it easily into a small clean project.

The problem is, we have such code in test:

```
let(:user) { mock(...) }

it "should do something" do
    user.should_receive(:name=)
    put :update, :user_id=>1, { :name => "newname" }
end

it "should not do something" do
    user.should_not_receive(:name=)
    put :update, :user_id=>1, { :name => "newname" }
end
```

These two tests are both passed but their only difference is one using `should_receive` and another one using `should_not_receive`.

I have done some researches and found some guy have similar problems:

- [RSpec for should_receive and should_not_receive both passed for Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319975/rspec-for-should-receive-and-should-not-receive-both-passed-for-exception)
- https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/164

Now I am looking for some workaround to still be able to check if a method has been called or not. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in rspec 2.14.1?

Comment: I tried with 2.14.1, have same problem

Comment: Try the `expect(x).to(receive(:y))` syntax in 2.14.1

Comment: Are `mock` and `double` the same?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the controller test, you have a different instance of `user` that in the controller itself.

Add the line `puts user.object_id` to the spec, and `puts @user.object_id` to the controller, and you will see this.  (Different object_id's means they are not the same object.)

Even though they refer to the same entity (i.e. they both were loaded using the same record in the database and have the same id), they are different instances.  A more general way to see this is the following:

```
user == User.find(user.id) # => true
user.object_id == User.find(user.id).object_id # => false
```

`should_receive` is failing because it tests that you call `:name=` on the instance in the test, which you don't.  But you may actually be calling `:name=` on the instance in the controller.

`should_not_receive` is passing because it tests that you never call `:name=` on the instance in the spec.  But this isn't what you want to test.  You want to test that you never call `:name=` on the instance in the controller.

This is the risk with negative assertions in general.  False positives are common in tests like there.

A better way to test would be to verify side-effects of the methods.  For example:

```
expect{ put :update, :user_id=>1, { :name => "newname" }}.
  to change{user.reload.name}.from(...).to(...)
# You'll have to fill in the `...`
```

Now, it doesn't matter whether it did this by calling `user.name=` or by setting the name some other way (`user[:name] = ...`, `user.public_send(:name=, "..."`, etc.).  If you changed the implementation in the controller, you want it to continue to pass the test, because what you really care about is whether the name changed in the DB.  But the way you've written the tests now, even once you get them passing, they would fail if you changed the controller implementation.